# Inverse of Normal CDF

Tags: normal-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am trying to find $a$ that satisfies the following.

$P(X>1+a) = \frac{\alpha}{2}$ for given $\alpha \in (0,1)$ where $X \sim \mathcal{N}(1, 1.5^2)$

To solve this, I'd like to take the inverse of the Normal CDF to both sides over the following:

$CDF(1+a) = 1-\frac{\alpha}{2}$

Any idea how to apply $CDF^-1$? I can't find closed form of inverse function of CDF.

Comment: The normal CDF and its inverse don't have closed form solutions. Use python's `scipy.stats` functons `norm.cdf`and `norm.ppdf`.

Comment: The Casio has InvNormCD(lower limit, upper limit, standard deviation, mean)